# Running cucumber feature in a project invokes step definition in another project

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am new to cucumber and selenium, my question may seem very trivial, but I couldn't find an answer on my own.
I have 2 projects with similar functionality, when I run cucumber feature in the new project, step definition from the old project is executed!
Can someone explain why this is happening?
[Screen shot from eclipse showing the 2 projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRMGa.png)

Comment: Check you run configuration in eclipse. The project path vs path in the console log doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: You are right and my problem is fixed. Thank you so much.